# Is there a way to make a telnet session connect, issue a comment and disconnect?

Tags: powershell, vbscript, telnet

We have a Fluke 1620A "Dewk" hygrometer that we use in our lab. Before we would have to go over to the unit hanging high up on the wall, and get temp and humidity. Since it is connected to our LAN, I was able to make a batch file, and vb script to connect to it and retrieve the temp and RH. But since only 1 person can connect at a time, I had to use a 60 sec timer to sever the connection and close the little cmd windows, that stay open during the 60 secs.

Here is my batch file

```
cls

@echo off 
:: Open a Telnet window

:: start telnet.exe 192.168.20.9 10001
start telnet.exe
:: Run the script
cscript SendKeys.vbs


@echo off

set /a "t=60"
:loop
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > nul
set /a "t-=1"
if "%t%" == "0" goto timedout
cls
Echo Closing Telnet in %t% seconds! 
goto loop

:timedout
Taskkill /im telnet.exe
:: pause
goto :eof
```

And here is my .vbs code

```
set OBJECT=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")



WScript.sleep(500)
OBJECT.SendKeys "o 192.168.20.9 10001{ENTER}"

OBJECT.SendKeys "Read? 1{ENTER}"
```

Very simple. But I was wondering if I could get the code to ping the Dewk every few seconds to send the Read? 1  command and retrieve the temp and RH. That way it could just change the numbers retrieved, every ping.  I guess to simulate live readings. And Allow other people to connect at the same time.

Is there a way for powershell or vbs to do this. I've tried changing the code to disconnect and reconnect but some reason, it won't connect the second time, unless I close all the windows and start over.

So the above code works, just 60 seconds at a time, and only 1 person at a time.

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Google is your friend: https://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/1887-get-telnet-telnet-to-a-device-and-issue-commands

Comment: This might be overkill, but you *could* consider a dedicated machine keeping an open connection to the fluke and “publishing” the readings real-time to somewhere in a shared location - e.g. saving to a csv on a file share or hosting a simple static file web app with the files on. That way there no contention for the constrained resource (i.e. the fluke), and you also have a historical dataset to pull from later.